PointerPressed not working in DataTemplate
I have following xaml:
<ListBox PointerPressed="OnPressed"         
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid PointerPressed="OnPressed">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

And code behind:
public void OnPressed(object? sender, PointerPressedEventArgs? args)
{
     //some logic to handle PointerPressed event
}

PointerPressed on ListBox works, but PointerPressed on Grid (inside ListBox ItemTeplate) doesn't work, even when I remove PointerPressed from ListBox.
Do I miss something here?

UI elements only receive mouse input in areas where they have non-null drawing content.
Set Background="Transparent" (or any other Brush) on the Grid to make its whole are hit-test visible.
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" PointerPressed="OnPressed">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>


While this is not a straight answer for my problem, it really helped me find a solution. I changed background of the Grid to some color, to see how the Grid actually looks on the screen.  It turned out, that the Grid was entirely  under the TextBox. I got misled by the look of the ListBoxItem while using Fluent Theme. While this theme is active, ListBoxItem gets some additional space around actual DataTemplate. I thought that this space was part of the Grid.  When I switched to Simple Theme, additional space was gone. Thanks for the help!
